# Clip/Crop background-image with react and css

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have this HTML:

```
 <div className="img" />
```

with this Css:

```
.row2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 1790px;
  height: 983px;
  background-image: url("/img.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #d0c6b5;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;

  @media (min-width: 375px) and (max-width: 414px) {
  
  }
}
```

[image]

and i`m going to use media query to show only this part of the screen.
how can i do?

[image]

Comment: In the css file, className is img!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For responsive designing's you will not be able to get the exact crop for all the dimensions. However you can use **px** to get almost the same crop for the devices.

Mainly you have to play around the **background-position** attribute. See reference code below

```
 @media (min-width: 375px) and (max-width: 414px) {
  width: 350px;
  height: 600px;
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIWX6.png');
  background-position: -950px 0;
  background-size: 650px 100%;
  }
```

Comment: div width should be 350px.
However, I changed the location value a little after setting width to 350px, but it is different from the area I want. I think it's because the background-image is big, but I think we should reduce it and apply it. What should i do?

this is my code
```
 background-size: cover;
    width: 320px !important;
    background-position: -390px 0 !important;
```

Comment: Updated my answer. Again this will not result same for every device you will use.